# Getting react passed props & redux state at same time in component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im trying to get access to redux state but im also need props that passed from routing.

The example is: i need that **props**

```
const DefaultLayout = props => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

because

```
<Route
   path="/"
   name="Home"
   render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props} />}
/>
```

when i add redux state like: **{auth: {user}}** to access user data, its not working.

```
const DefaultLayout = (props , {auth: {user}}) => {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

**...**

```
DefaultLayout.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DefaultLayout);
```

if i delete that **props** i will getting pathname error, any explanation and help? new to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const DefaultLayout = (props , {auth: {user}}) => {`

Components just get passed a single variable: props. If you want to access auth.user, it's found at `props.auth.user`. It's put there by `mapStateToProps` in cooperation with `connect`

```
const DefaultLayout = (props) => {
  const { location, history, match, auth } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      // something with the variables 
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DefaultLayout);
```

Comment: I see now. Thanks for the great explanation, just know that. Because im rarely passing props & need to use redux state at the same time. i've been doin the wrong way, **const { user } =auth;** instead haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to access the props this way :

```
const DefaultLayout = ({auth, location, history, ...otherProps}) => {
//example : console.log(otherProps.match);
    return (
        <div>
            {auth.user}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Props passed by the Route component are merged with the props added by redux.

Comment: This also works and more tidy because match my code style, Thank you.